# JavaScript loading out of time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working in a Rails project and I was doing a simple click alert kind of function like this:

**html.erb**

```
<%= button_tag 'button', type: 'button', class: 'right-button' %>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(".right-button").on("click", alert("right-button clicked!"));
```

The problem is that when I load the page (ctrl + F5), the alert is triggered without even pressing the button and when I press the button, nothing happens. I already tried to use:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
});
```

But it didn't work either. I even tried to put the JavaScript insede the **html.erb**:

```
<%= button_tag 'button', type: 'button', class: 'right-button' %>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".right-button").on("click", alert("right-button clicked!"));
</script>
```

If you know what is happening, please help, thanks!

PS: Turbolinks are disabled!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you're immediately invoking your `alert`. Parenthesis after a function means that you're calling said function.

What you want to do is call `alert` from *within* your click handler's callback so that when the callback is invoked for your click event, the `alert` fires.

```js
// Incorrect
$(".right-button").on("click", alert("Immediately Invoked"));

// Correct
$(".right-button").on("click", function() {
  alert("Invoked on-click");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="right-button">Click Me!</button>
```

Additionally if the element is injected dynamically, you'll have to turn to event delegation to handle that.

```js
$('.add-section').on('click', function() {
  $('#container').append('<section><button class="click-me">Click Me!</button></section>');  
});

$('#container').on('click', '.click-me', function() {
  alert('Event delegation!!!!!!!!!!!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="container">
  <button class="add-section">Add section!</button>
</div>
```

What this does is targets a parent node of the dynamic content and attaches a click handler to it. We pass the selector that matches the node which will be dynamically added. Any clicks which occur on nodes within `#container` will be checked to see if they match `.click-me`, if they do then the callback will be fired.

Comment: What you said makes a lot of sense. I did this but it doesn't load either. When I copy the code to the console (F12), it works, but not inside the proper code.

Comment: "it works, but not inside the proper code", can you elaborate? Also can you try updating your actual code, instead of in console, and try it out? Updating the question with the exact code you're using will also be beneficial as well.

Comment: What I meant to say is that it is working when I execute from the console, but nothing happens when I load the page. The code is simple as I showed. I think the problem is something that Rails is doing when loading the JS.

Comment: Are you only testing this in the chrome console? Or have you updated your javascript file to contain the correct example? You only want it to alert when the button is clicked, correct?

Comment: No, I'm testing it with both. I updated the JavaScript file as you suggested, but it's not working, only when I run it from the console. Yes, when the button is clicked.

Comment: Yes, it is still wrapped

Comment: Can you just append *exactly* what you have to the question? Something's not adding up. It works in the interactive example within my answer, so something seems to be wrong with your code and it's hard to tell without seeing something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122130/discussion-between-seth-and-raven-the-bard).